# How do I use a specific column's value in a Pandas DataFrame where clause?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm trying to select all cells in a pandas DataFrame that meet a certain criteria when a specific column also meets a separate criteria.

Given the following DataFrame:

```
      A    B    C    D
1/1   0    1    0    1
1/2   2    1    1    1
1/3   3    0    1    0 
1/4   1    0    1    2
1/5   1    0    1    1
1/6   2    0    2    1
1/7   3    5    2    3
```

I would like to somehow select the data where a column is greater than its previous value, when `D` is also > 1.  The syntax I'm trying to use currently is:

```
matches = df[(df > df.shift(1)) & (df.D > 1)]
```

However, when i do this, I receive the following error:

> TypeError: Could not operate [array([nan, nan, nan, nan],
>   dtype=object)] with block values [operands could not be broadcast
>   together with shapes (2016) (4) ]

Note: the error is a direct copy and past from my actual code, so the description and the shape in the error would not correlate directly to my example DataFrame.

I know that the `df.D > 1` is causing the problem, and comparing columns directly to `D` is valid (`df > df.D` for example).  What is wrong with my syntax when trying to compare `D` to the value `1`, and how could I accomplish this?

Comment: What happens when you try `df[df > df.shift(1)][df.D > 1]`? does this achieve what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This *should* work directly, but pandas doesn't have a broadcasting and operator (will happenin 0.14). Here's a workaround.

```
In [74]: df
Out[74]: 
     A  B  C  D
1/1  0  1  0  1
1/2  2  1  1  1
1/3  3  0  1  0
1/4  1  0  1  2
1/5  1  0  1  1
1/6  2  0  2  1
1/7  3  5  2  3
```

This is a where operation, essentially put `np.nan` where the condition is False

```
In [78]: x = df[df>df.shift(1)]

In [79]: x
Out[79]: 
      A   B   C   D
1/1 NaN NaN NaN NaN
1/2   2 NaN   1 NaN
1/3   3 NaN NaN NaN
1/4 NaN NaN NaN   2
1/5 NaN NaN NaN NaN
1/6   2 NaN   2 NaN
1/7   3   5 NaN   3
```

Select by the 2nd condition

```
In [80]: x[df.D>1]
Out[80]: 
      A   B   C  D
1/4 NaN NaN NaN  2
1/7   3   5 NaN  3
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  So if I understand correctly, `(df > df.shift(1)) & (df > 1.0)` do work because both DataFrames used in this case have the same shape.  However since `df.D` is just a 1-dimensional vector `df.D > 1.0` cannot be used in conjunction with an operation against the entire DataFrame.  Does that sound correct?

Comment: yes....the issue is the Series vector (e.g. ``df.D>1``) *looks* like it should work, but its ambiguous how it should broadcast, e.g. should that Series named D apply to all of the other columns (in which case what should it do?), or should it effectively have no name which means it SHOULD broadcast. You problem could also be solved by using ``df>1.0`` because I think that is what you intend (e.g. that it DOES broadcast)

Comment: Is it possible to somehow execute the second select WITHOUT removing the rows that don't meet the criteria, rather leaving them as all `NaN` rows like you see after the first statement executes?  For my specific requirements, the original shape must be maintained.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is actually that the boolean array from the shift operation is one short of the the other conditional.  Try adding a false to the first conditional at index zero you should then be able to combine the two conditionals.

I'd the problem really is with the second conditional could you post the result of

```
DF.dtypes
```

it looks like it's not  int type given the nan array error