# Filtering a Pandas DataFrame Without Removing Rows

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to use `where` on my Pandas DataFrame in replace all cells that don't meet my criteria with `NaN`.  Howevever, I'd like to do it in such a way that will always preserve the shape of my original DataFrame, and not remove any rows from the resulting DataFrame.

Given the following DataFrame:

```
      A    B    C    D
1/1   0    1    0    1
1/2   2    1    1    1
1/3   3    0    1    0 
1/4   1    0    1    2
1/5   1    0    1    1
1/6   2    0    2    1
1/7   3    5    2    3
```

I would like to search the dataframe for all cells that meet a certain criteria, when column `D` ALSO meets a particular criteria.    In this case my criteria is:

**Find all cells that are greater than the previous value, when column D is also > 1**

I accomplish this by using the following syntax:

```
matches = df[df > df.shift(1))]
matches = matches[df.D > 1]
```

I have to split this query into two statements because of the fact that `df.D` is a Series and does not match the shape of the entire DataFrame.  According to [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484344/how-do-i-use-a-specific-columns-value-in-a-pandas-dataframe-where-clause) I asked previously, support for a broadcasting `&` operator will not be available until 0.14.

The problem I am having is that it seems like after I run the second statement, the shape of the resulting data frame is changed and rows have been removed.  The number of columns stays the same.  The first statement leaves the original number of rows.

Why would the second statement remove rows while the first does not?  How could I achieve the same result, but leaving the full number of rows in tact?

**Edit:**

The pandas documentation states that in order to guarantee that the shape is preserved, I should use the `where` method over boolean indexing. However, that does not seem to be allowed to perform my second statement, so:

```
matches.where(df.D > 1)
```

Gives me the following error:

> ValueError: Array conditional must be same shape as self

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is slightly more intuitive than @DSM answer (but pandas missing this type of auto-broadcasting on boolean ops ATM)

```
In [58]: df.where((df>df.shift(1)).values & DataFrame(df.D==1).values)
Out[58]: 
      A   B   C   D
1/1 NaN NaN NaN NaN
1/2   2 NaN   1 NaN
1/3 NaN NaN NaN NaN
1/4 NaN NaN NaN NaN
1/5 NaN NaN NaN NaN
1/6   2 NaN   2 NaN
1/7 NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5284) for the issue to be addressed in 0.14

Comment: Thanks Jeff, that worked perfectly.  Do you know if there are any performance issues with switching to the numpy arrays?  Do I miss out on any performance optimizations that a pandas dataframe would provide?  It was certainly performant enough in my actual, larger use case, but just curious.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what you're after, you can do the broadcasting manually by dropping down to the `numpy` level:

```
>>> (df > df.shift(1)).values & (df.D == 1)[:,None]
array([[False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

after which you can use `where`:

```
>>> df.where((df > df.shift(1)).values & (df.D == 1)[:,None], np.nan)
      A   B   C   D
1/1 NaN NaN NaN NaN
1/2   2 NaN   1 NaN
1/3 NaN NaN NaN NaN
1/4 NaN NaN NaN NaN
1/5 NaN NaN NaN NaN
1/6   2 NaN   2 NaN
1/7 NaN NaN NaN NaN
```