# ValueError when using the DataFrame.where method in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, where-clause

I am writing the following code, and I want to get only the first 3 minutes of the values with `pd.where` method, but I get the following error:
ValueError: Array conditional must be same shape as self

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = pd.date_range(start = '2017-06-01 00:00', end='2017-06-01 01:00', freq='1min')
values = np.arange(0, len(index))
df = pd.DataFrame(values, index = index)

df.where(df.index <= df.index[0] + pd.DateOffset(minutes=3), np.nan)
```

There is an [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507088/filtering-a-pandas-dataframe-without-removing-rows) with this error but the contexts are different.

The code for integer index seems to work well, but for time series I have problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `df.where` after converting `df.index` to `series`

```
In [557]: df.where(df.index.to_series() <= df.index[0] + pd.DateOffset(minutes=3))
Out[557]:
                       0
2017-06-01 00:00:00  0.0
2017-06-01 00:01:00  1.0
2017-06-01 00:02:00  2.0
2017-06-01 00:03:00  3.0
2017-06-01 00:04:00  NaN
2017-06-01 00:05:00  NaN
2017-06-01 00:06:00  NaN
...                  ...
2017-06-01 00:57:00  NaN
2017-06-01 00:58:00  NaN
2017-06-01 00:59:00  NaN
2017-06-01 01:00:00  NaN

[61 rows x 1 columns]
```